# Pushing to array session - Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session, laravel-8

I want to store in a session array a shopping cart. I'm trying to do this:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    function add($id, Request $request) {
        if ($request->session()->missing('shopping_cart')) {
            $request->session()->put('shopping_cart', []);
        }

        $item = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'quntity'=> 1
        );

        $request->session()->push('shopping_cart', $item);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[
  0 => [
    "id" => "12"
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
]
```

But when I call another time the function add() it replace the array like so:

```
[
  0 => [
    "id" => "20"
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
  0 => [
    "id" => "12"
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
  1 => [
    "id" => "20"
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
  2 => [
    "id" => "27"
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because `shopping_cart` is an already defined key. So it will overwrite data with that key. The best thing you can do is create a unique item with the ID in that `shopping_cart` object. Something like;

```php
    function add($id, Request $request) {
        $shoppingCartKey = 'shopping_cart.'+ $id;
        $shoppingCartData = array(
            'quantity'=> 1
        );

        if ($request->session()->missing($shoppingCartKey)) {
            $request->session()->put($shoppingCartKey, []);
        }


        $request->session()->push($shoppingCartKey, $shoppingCartData);
    }
```

Now you're also able to get/pull data from the session based on the `shopping_cart` ID/key

Answer (score 0):

This will get you sorted as long as you carry the cart id to every function you wish to work with the cart. below is the add product to cart session

```
    public function addItem($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);

        if(!$post) {

            abort(404);

        }

        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        // if cart is empty then this the first product
        if(!$cart) {

            $cart = [
                $id => [
                    "name"          => $post->product_name,
                    "quantity"      => 1,
                    "price"         => $post->price,
                ]
            ];

            session()->put('cart', $cart);

            return redirect()->back()->with('toast_success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
        }

        // if cart not empty then check if this product exist then increment quantity
        if(isset($cart[$id])) {

            $cart[$id]['quantity']++;

            session()->put('cart', $cart);

            return redirect()->back()->with('toast_success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');

        }

        // if item not exist in cart then add to cart with quantity = 1
        $cart[$id] = [
            "name"          => $post->product_name,
            "quantity"      => 1,
            "price"         => $post->price,
        ];

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('toast_success', 'Product added !!');
    }
```